# Group by then filter the groups with condition

Tags: pandas, group-by

col

```
Batch result
```

first group by with batch and then filter groups with condition on result column

**Code**

```
 for key, value in df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7]):
        print('\n****',key,'****', '\n\n', value['result'].isnull())
```

**Output**

```
**** qwe6404 **** 
 19099    False
19126    False
Name: Result, dtype: bool

**** qwe8135 **** 

 18863     True
18866    False
Name: Result, dtype: bool
```

Also tried

```
.filter(lambda g: ( g.result.isnull().sum() == 2 ))
```

How I can filter Groups having both `True` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.batch.str[:7]).filter(lambda g: g.result.isnull().all())
```

For improve performance use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.result.isnull().groupby(df.batch.str[:7]).transform('all')]
```